# Looping through mongoDB result in PHP throws unusual error - Cannot use object of type MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime as array

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm retrieving array from mongoDB which has the following structure:

```
'dataINeed' =>
    array
      0 => 
     'stringINeed' => string 'something'
     'dateTimeCreated' => 
         object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)[4569]
         public 'milliseconds' => string '1527256881000' (length=13)
     'dateTimeUpdated' => 
         object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)[4513]
         public 'milliseconds' => string '1527257089000' (length=13)
      1 => 
     'stringINeed' => string 'something2'
     'dateTimeCreated' => 
          object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)[4569]
          public 'milliseconds' => string '1527256881000' (length=13)
     'dateTimeUpdated' => 
          object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)[4513]
          public 'milliseconds' => string '1527257089000' (length=13)
      3 => 
     'stringINeed' => string 'something3'
     'dateTimeCreated' => 
          object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)[4569]
          public 'milliseconds' => string '1527256881000' (length=13)
     'dateTimeUpdated' => 
          object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)[4513]
          public 'milliseconds' => string '1527257089000' (length=13)
```

I am trying to build an array containing 'strinINeed' in a following way:

```
foreach($resultSet['dataINeed'] as $singleResult) {
   $stringArray = $singleResult['stringINeed'];
}
```

The code above produces error:

```
Cannot use object of type MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime as array
```

Even though I'm not accessing the dateTimeCreated or dateTimeUpdated fields. They are just in the array that I'm looping over.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show the code that you obtained `$resultSet` from. Also check that the driver you are working with is the [PHPLIB](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/) driver and not the core driver, as the "core" is meant for lower level development and you want the PHPLIB one instead.

Comment: Have you tried a var_dump on $singleResult? I suspect you'll find it's an object rather than an array.